# extract pandas subset if values are in list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract a DataFrame subset, I want all rows where the first column is in a specific list.
For example I have:

```
        t   gid
0   2010.0  1
1   2020.0  4
2   2040.0  6
3   2060.0  6
4   2090.0  12
5   2110.0  18
6   2140.0  1000
```

and I want a DataFrame of all rows where gid is in q_list == [1,6,18]

Comment: Use `df[df.gid.isin(q_list)]`, check [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: @jezrael Great! witht your second answer I got from 45sec to 3.68 !

Comment: super, it is really good

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the column to the index and use smart indexing:

```
df.set_index('gid').ix[q_list]
```